# Почему std::greater() не работает с самонаписанной структрурой?

Tags: c++

У меня есть структура triple, для которой определен оператор больше:

```
struct triple
{
    int c, v, u;
    
    triple(int cn, int vn, int un)
    {
        c = cn, v = vn, u = un;
    }

    bool operator >(triple n)
    {
        if (c > n.c)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Если я пытаюсь запустить следующий код, то программа падает с ошибкой C2678 (бинарный ">": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "const _Ty" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)):

```
int main()
{
    triple a(10, 1, 2);
    triple b(20, 2, 3);
    priority_queue<triple, vector<triple>, greater<triple>> q;
    q.push(a);
    q.push(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Если вне структуры объявить оператор больше с нужной сигнатурой и такой реализацией, то программа падает с ошибкой Stack overflow:

```
bool operator >(const triple& a, const triple& b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```

А в такой реализации программа отрабатывает правильно и без ошибок, хотя по идее она ничем не отличается от предыдущей:

```
bool operator >(const triple& a, const triple& b)
{
    if (a.c > b.c)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Сам вопрос:
Почему плюсы не могут сравнить константные выражения по ссылке так же, как и обычные?
И как можно объявить нужный оператор сравнения внутри самой структуры, чтобы он не путался под ногами вне ее определения?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В таком виде как вы написали, оператор может вызываться только для не константных объектов, а `operator()`  объекта `greater<triple>` принимает ссылки на константные объекты, поэтому нужно переписать оператор:

```
struct triple
{
    //...
    bool operator >(const triple& n) const
    //добавлен const, чтобы вызвать  для константных объектов тоже
    {
        
        return c > n.c;
    }
};
```

Тогда не будет никакой ошибки. Теперь рассмотрим другой вариант.

Когда вы определяете оператор вне структуры(как свободный оператор), то так:

```
bool operator >(const triple& a, const triple& b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```

Вы практически в операторе рекурсивно вызываете этот же оператор, поэтому кроме как переполнения стека, ничего не случается. То, что у вас работает многим отличается от этого оператора. Он уже сравнивает члены, для которых определен оператор сравнения.

Если убрать лишнюю писанину, то рабочий оператор то же самое, что и:

```
bool operator >(const triple& a, const triple& b)
{    
    return a.c > b.c;
}
```

Заметили различие с предыдущим оператором?...